# Eks helm - yaml problems

Tags: json, yaml, devops, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm using helm to deploy to EKS, the problem is **Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bundle exec sidekiq --environment dev": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown**

this **value.yml**:

```
sidekiqCommand:
  - "bundle"
  - "exec"
  - "sidekiq"
  - "--environment"
  - "dev"
```

and **deployment.yml**:

```
name: sidekiq
       securityContext:
         {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
       image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
       imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
       command: {{ .Values.sidekiqCommand }}
```

When running locally, or when I put this command to the ENTRYPOINT of the container, everything works. But when I deploy it using Helm charts - no , I guess the problem may be that it is not processing correctly yml to json

everything works perfectly when

```
name: sidekiq
       securityContext:
         {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
       image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
       imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
command: ["bundle", "exec", "sidekiq", "--environment", "dev"]
```

I was trying to pass a list of arguments, and replaced `{{ .Values.sidekiqCommand }}` with the following code:

```
{{- $command := .Values.sidekiqCommand }}
command:
{{- range $arg := $command }}
  - {{ $arg }}
{{- end }}
```

but it didn't work that way either((

Comment: Problem is with your image, not with helm. Try running this image locally with same command via docker or podman and debug there.

Comment: @taleodor everything works locally, and even works when I put the command to deployment.yml, but does not work when I pull from value.yml

Comment: It may only mean you're not using same command locally vs helm. Try deploying via plain yaml also to debug. But problem is image doesn't have 'bundle' command - so see what it should be and try to fix.

Comment: @taleodor docker run -it -d id.dkr.ecr.reg.amazonaws.com/sq:9qr27c4 bundle exec puma -e stage -p 5005 -S ~/puma -C config/puma.rb -> docker logs name
->>>Puma starting in single mode...           ,,,here the problem is not in the image, here the problem is that I cannot transfer the command from value.yml to deployment.yml, moreover, if I write the command in deployment.yml, everything works

Comment: look at difference between command + entrypoint and args in docker and kubernetes - do some research on the subj, seems like you're mixing the two and they differ between docker and kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

If you run `helm template --debug` on your chart, what you will see is the `command:` rendered to a default Go format that happens to be syntactically valid YAML, but doesn't have the right meaning.  I'd expect it to look something like

```yaml
command: [bundle exec sidekiq --environment dev]
```

which is a YAML list with a single element, which gets processed as a single shell word.

You need to force this to be a YAML list, probably using the [`toYaml`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) function, like

```yaml
        command:
{{ .Values.sidekiqCommand | toYaml | indent 10 }}
```

(where `command:`'s natural indentation is 8 spaces, and the `indent 10` value is two spaces more than that, but the `{{ ... | indent }}` line is not itself indented).

(There's a good argument that this shouldn't be configurable at all: it's hard to imagine someone trying to deploy this chart but wanting the `sidekiq` Deployment to do something other than run a Sidekiq worker.  I might just write out the command directly in the `templates/deployment-sidekiq.yaml` file.)